# Codigniter Encode in version 1.7 decode in version 2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, decode, encode

Anyone got this problem before?

From codignier v1.7 i encode some data in order to provide web service to another site using codignier 2.0

```
$to_send =  $this->encrypt->encode($data, '12345');
```

To another site using codignier 2.0 to get data from curl
if i dont encode and decode, data from curl is fine.

```
$to_get = $this->encrypt->decode($data, '12345');
```

I also try to add this to both site of website , but still not help in case it got some thing change in default value.

```
$this->encrypt->set_cipher(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256);
$this->encrypt->set_mode(MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
```

when echo $to_get data is not usable

```
"^6>þ×È·¾ˆ­÷Íón´= wÁSùçâÈþbåNÚÁ»¿_óÈÔfÞã@sf=µ@¹vÏŽ§ÃíŽÞ"
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your `encryption_key` is the same on both sites (located inside the application/config/config.php file)?

Comment: $this->encrypt->decode($data, '12345'); in both site , so system will use one you put, "12345"

Comment: Oh, i see (now), please check the answer with the upgrade guide.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`encode_from_legacy`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html#legacy) method in the Encryption library introduced with the 2.0.0 updates. See the [upgrading guide's Step 4.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrade_200.html) for more information.

Also make sure that you use the old site's encryption key when using the method (via the configuration files or passed in explicitly).